# BufferedReader does not read all the lines in text file

Tags: java

I have a function.

```
public ArrayList<String> readRules(String src) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(src))) {
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            lines.add(sCurrentLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

My file have 26.400 lines but this function just read 3400 lines at end of file.
How do I read all lines in file.
Thanks!

Comment: Since you use Java 7, why don't you use `Files.readAllLines()` instead? Even if you don't, you should use `Path` and `Files.newBufferedReader()`

Comment: Where are you defining `lines` ?  Otherwise this would read all the lines of a file, if something is wrong I would look elsewhere.

Comment: Understand `readLine()` method _Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed._

Comment: would it be possible for you to post lines 3400 and 3401 here? If there are any special character, make sure that is highlighted please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
```

It is likely that you have an empty line or a line that is treated as `null`.

Try

```
while(br.hasNextLine())
{
    String current = br.nextLine();
}
```

**Edit:** Or, in your text file, when a line is too long, the editor automatically wraps a single line into many lines. When you don't use `return key`, it is treated as a single line by BufferedReader.

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a good tool to prevent confusing a single line with multiple lines. It numbers the lines with respect to usage of return key. Maybe you could copy/paste your input file to `Notepad++` and check if the line numbers match.

Comment: What he does is correct, BufferedReader.readLine() is returning null only if the end of stream has been reached. Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). An empty line would be retrieved as and empty String (`""`) which is not `null`. What line would be "treated as `null`"?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the utility method `Files.readAllLines()` (available since Java 7)?

This method ensures that the file is closed when all bytes have been read or an IOException (or another runtime exception) is thrown.

Bytes from the file are decoded into characters using the specified charset.

```
public ArrayList<String> readRules(String src) {
    return Files.readAllLines(src, Charset.defaultCharset());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have not know have readAllLines() yet. Your comment is very useful.

Comment: You should pass a `Path` object as parameter to `readAllLines()`. Strings are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can also cast into a List of strings using readAllLines() and then loop through it.

```
List<String> myfilevar = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/PATH/TO/MY/FILE.TXT"));
for(String x : myfilevar)
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```